# C# multiple reusable worker threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to build some kind of multi-thread game engine with reusable worker threads. That means the workers are running an endless loop and, after every iteration, call a method that suspends the thread with an `AutoResetEvent` until the next iteration is started from outside. Thet works fine.
But then I want to wait for all of the worker threads to get into the waiting state. But the last thread is always ignored in the first step.
This is my code:

```
class WorkerThread
{
    private readonly Game game;
    private readonly Task task;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent waitEvent;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent finishEvent;

    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; private set; }

    public WorkerThread(Game game)
    {
        this.game = game;
        waitEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        finishEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        task = new Task(startTask);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        task.Start();
    }

    public void PerformFrame()
    {
        finishEvent.Reset();
        waitEvent.Set();
    }

    public void WaitForFrameToFinish()
    {
        finishEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    private void startTask()
    {
        WaitFrame();
        run();
    }

    long sum;
    private void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                sum += i;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Message);
            WaitFrame();
        }
    }

    private void WaitFrame()
    {
        Active = false;
        finishEvent.Set();
        waitEvent.WaitOne();
        Active = true;
    }
}

class Game
{
    private readonly List<WorkerThread> workers = new List<WorkerThread>();

    public Game()
    {
        workers.Add(new WorkerThread(this) { Message = "Worker 1" });
        workers.Add(new WorkerThread(this) { Message = "Worker 2" });
        workers.Add(new WorkerThread(this) { Message = "Worker 3" });
        workers.Add(new WorkerThread(this) { Message = "Worker 4" });
        workers.Add(new WorkerThread(this) { Message = "Worker 5" });
        workers.Add(new WorkerThread(this) { Message = "Worker 6" });
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        foreach (WorkerThread worker in workers)
        {
            worker.Start();
        }
    }

    public void OneFrame()
    {
        //start every worker
        foreach (WorkerThread worker in workers)
        {
            worker.PerformFrame();
        }

        //wait for the workers to finish
        foreach (WorkerThread worker in workers)
        {
            worker.WaitForFrameToFinish();
        }

        //check if there are workers still running
        foreach (WorkerThread worker in workers)
        {
            if (worker.Active)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(worker.Message + " still active");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Frame finished.\n");
    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea why the `Game` doen't wait for the last `WorkerThread` do finish its task?

EDIT: Using a `ManualResetEventSlim` instead of an `AutoResetEvent` solves the problem. But I still don't understand why the above doesn't work.

EDIT 2: I found the answer and posted it below.

Comment: The code works for me. How do you determine that it does not wait for the last thread?

Comment: Calling `Game.Start()` followed by `Game.OneFrame()` produces the following output:
    `Worker 1
    Worker 2
    Worker 4
    Worker 3
    Worker 5
    Worker 6 still active
    Frame finished.
    
    Worker 6`

Comment: @Skinnix that could be from cached data, you might need to put a memory fence around `Active` like by putting the read and write of `Active` inside a `lock` or switching from a auto property to one with a backing store with a [`VolitileRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.volatileread(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain sounds plausible but changing the `Active` property to using `Volatile.Read` and `Volatile.Write` does not seem to change anything...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Actually, you made a good point. In further implementations memory fences and thread-safety will be a serious issue. I will have to think about that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution. `startTask` uses the `WaitFrame` method that sets the `finishEvent`. That way `WaitForFrameToFinish` will not wait for the worker on the first iteration because `finishEvent` is already set.
If you do it like this, it works fine:

```
private void startTask()
{
    waitEvent.WaitOne();
    waitEvent.Reset();
    finishEvent.Reset();

    run();
}
```